# NodeJS REPL double echoing input, making it hard to use

Tags: node.js

When I use the NodeJS repl on linux, everything I type is echoed twice. If I start it up like this:

```sh
$ node
Welcome to Node.js v16.11.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> let repl;
undefined
> import("repl").then(module => { repl = module });
Promise {
  <pending>,
  [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 294,
  [Symbol(trigger_async_id_symbol)]: 283,
  [Symbol(destroyed)]: { destroyed: false }
}
> let f = repl.start();
> undefined
>
```

Now everything that I type is doubled up. If I type the letter `d`, it shows `dd`. This is preventing me from creating my own REPL setup script.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start node.js in a terminal without passing a javascript file, by default node actually creates a REPL instance behind the scenes to give you something to interact with in your terminal. So by importing and starting another REPL you now have two REPL instances reading stdin and so you get twice the echo of stdin to stdout.

You can access the default running REPL by running `this.repl` in a newly opened node terminal. If you want only your own REPL to run, I would recommend declaring your REPL in a javascript file and then executing that file with the node runtime instead.

Comment: This wasn't the answer, but it did help me find the answer, so I am going to mark it correct. The problem was that I had a `console.ts` that would load and run `repl.start`. However, instead of running `ts-node ./src/console.ts`, I was running `ts-node -r ./src/console.ts` and this caused it to run two interpreters at the same time.